# ip range pattern in web.config

Tags: asp.net, regex, web-config, web.config-transform

I want to redirect all the ip's in  between 83.116.119.0 to 255.255.255.0
Please help me to write a pattern in my code(IPTOBEBLOCKED).
Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="Redirect Japan Users" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="IPTOBEBLOCKED"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.net/jp/" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you sure that all ip addresses (which you want to redirect) greater than 83.116.119.0 - Japanese? I've got an ip in 83.246.*.* and I'm russian. Googled some example https://serverfault.com/questions/447669/blocking-requests-from-specific-ips-using-iis-rewrite-module

Comment: @sedo   its just an example